# ComplexType inside ComplexType

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype

I'm trying to place element which is optional inside a simpleType element, so I changed it to complexType. Now I have complexType inside complexType and validator says it's wrong, how do I fix it?

```
 <glowne_role>
    <aktor>William H. Macy</aktor>
    <aktor>
      Frances McDormand
      <komentarz>Prywatnie aktorka jest żoną reżysera.</komentarz>
    </aktor>
  </glowne_role>


<xs:element name="komentarz" type="xs:string" />

<xs:complexType name="glowne_role">
  <xs:complexType name="aktor" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3" type="xs:string">
    <xs:element ref="komentarz" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a `xs:complexType` inside a `xs:complexType`, but not directly.  Based on your XML, you want to define an element, `glowne_role`, to be of complex type consisting of a sequence of `aktor` elements, each of which *then in turn* can also be of complex type.  Note that to allow text to precede or follow your `komentarz` you can set `mixed="true"` on the parent `xs:complexType`.

Altogether, then, this XSD will successfully validate your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="komentarz" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="glowne_role">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="aktor" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="komentarz" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```